# Knative pod http request

Tags: go, kubernetes, knative

When I make request for this started server: https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/1180479de480d7e36d6d7aef08babe59#file-server

I get right response:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Go-http-client/1.1"
  }, 
  "origin": "", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

But when I make request to that server on minikube which was created this way:
https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/1180479de480d7e36d6d7aef08babe59#file-serve-yaml

I get error:

```
ERROR: Get https://httpbin.org/get: EOF<nil>
```

How can I make http requests from kubernetes pod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knative uses [Istio](https://istio.io) and Istio, by default, doesn't allow outbound traffic to external hosts, such as httpbin.org. That's why your request is failing.

Follow [this document](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/f31d7106a119b453b0dbf208c3b1c0d698af4323/serving/outbound-network-access.md) to learn how to configure Knative (so that it configures Istio correctly) to make outbound connections. Or, you can directly configure the Istio by adding an egress policy: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/